# I've just noticed a bunch of questions tagged with [2008]

Tags: support, retag-request

If you check out https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/2008 there are about 10 or so.

There were more, but I retagged the obvious ones (the ones tagged `[windows]` `[server]` `[2008]`).

There are also 16 tagged with `[2003]` - https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/2003

It would be worth someone with a bit more knowledge than me checking the rest to remove these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [2008] eradicated

I got rid of all the [2003]'s except for one that was migrated.

I have also flooded almost the entire front page with the bumped questions. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's a hazard, but for the sake of organization I'll live with it!

Comment: And flooding the front page with corrections is *so much worse* than flooding it with answered questions where the questioner never came back to mark an answer... </sarcasm>